# Spyder + IPython keep accumulating memory with no way to free it

Tags: python, memory, ipython, spyder, ram

I am having troubles freeing the memory that my script uses when running it with Spyder 3.3.6 + IPython console. Everytime I run my script about 300 Mb get used and I cannot find a way to free them except restarting the console. If I do not close and restart the console every few runs, my whole system eventually freezes.

I tried %reset, gc.collect(), and all the clear variables commands I could find on Sypder, with no use.
Running the same exact script with Pycharm, I do observe the memory getting allocated, but it is freed as soon as the script is done running.

Downgrading the IPython console to version 5.8.0 helped speeding up significantly the reboot, but nonetheless the memory is not freed. Rebooting each time is quite annoying as it is slow and I always need to keep an eye on my system's memory.

Any idea what could cause this and how to solve it?
I am using Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

Thank you.

Comment: You (probably) have large variables in the global scope so either delete them or put your script into a function. It is also possible that you created a memory leak, without seeing your code its hard to tell

Comment: Nonetheless there should be a way to clear these variables?
I have tried putting my script inside a function but I see no significant change.

My script is very large and I use several external packages, so not sure what part of it I could upload to be helpful.

Comment: yes, restarting the interpreter.... it has no way of knowing your are done using something if you still maintain a reference to it. so either delete them yourself, wrap them in a context or restart the interpreter

Comment: aren't the commands such as %reset or gc.collect() meant to clear these?

Comment: from reading the docs it would appear that doing %reset and then gc.collect should work most of the time ["Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular float."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect), also [someone had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517289/7540911)