# Polars memory increases in Jupyter

Tags: memory, jupyter-notebook, python-polars

I am processing a dataset of 15 mio. rows from a parquet file with polars (windows 11, Python 3.11.4, Polars 0.20.16).

If I run the script for the first time the task manager shows 5.7 GB of ram usage for this python process. Then, if I execute the following part of the script again:

```
MASTER = DF.join(G, how="left", on="uid").filter([
    (pl.col("num") > 1) & (pl.col("num")<100)
]).sort("num").with_columns([(pl.col("lvl_1") + pl.lit("_") + pl.col("lvl_2")).alias("cat")])
```

ram usage increases to 7.7 GB. Then 9.6 Gb and so on.

Yes, I just can reset the notebook and execute  it again but I want to undestand why this is happening. As far as I can see, this part of the script always uses the same vars and does not create new ones. So the old data should be overwritten and ram usage not increase as the old data is replaced by exactly the same data. At least in theory.

Question:
Any idea, why this is happening and what I can do to free the memory?

Comment: Have you tried garbage collecting after running the cell (i.e. `import gc; gc.collect()`)?

Comment: You could also try `%reset out`, to delete all references to the cell output.

Comment: Hm, gc.collect() seems to work. Although not for the first re-execution but for the second. So ram usage increases to 7.7GB but not further. Thx.

But %reset causes problems as the cell does not stop executing. But even if it does not stay at 5.7 gb gc is already a good solution. 

Although I still not understand the problem as it seems to allocate always new memory and not reuse the existing one what would (probably) make sense.

Comment: In this case it seems like the intricacies of IPython's garbage collection are at play here. You could take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515085/python-garbage-collection-sometimes-not-working-in-jupyter-notebook) for more information.

Comment: Yeah, `Out[N]` is almost certainly keeping references alive past their usefulness.